# What is the difference between `when(foo, f)` and `when(foo).then(f)`

Tags: javascript, promise, when-js

I'm looking at some existing code that uses `when.js`. A pattern that appears a few times is:

```
return when(someBigFunction(), function() {
  doSomeMoreProcessing();
  if (maybe) {
    throw someError;
  }
});
```

I imagine the reason they use `when` here is they weren't sure at the time whether `someBigFunction()` would be returning a promise or not.

Is there a difference, semantically between the above and:

```
return when(someBigFunction()).then(function() {
...
});
```

Generally the examples don't make use of the return value of the promise (that is, it's `function() {` not `function(x) {`)
.

The API docs offer this:

- `when(x,f)`: Get a trusted promise by transforming x with f
- `then`: Transforms a promise's value by applying a function to the promise's fulfillment value.

So I suspect there is no difference, but maybe I'm missing a subtlety?

Comment: I always thought you did the .then() to decouple the data fetch from what you actually do with the data (so easier to test), but not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation itself](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/3f030f9010eea12ffcbf9fd48557dbf15a55a73e/when.js#L82) does clear this up:

```
function when(x, onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress) {
    var p = Promise.resolve(x);
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        return p;
    }

    return p.then(onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress);
}
```

There is **absolutely no difference** between `when(x,f)` and `when(x).then(f)`.

<sub>(Given that `.then(…)` does not care about its call stack or additional `undefined` arguments)</sub>

Today, it is purely sugar, as `when(x, f)` is shorter than its alternative or even the more efficient `Promise.resolve(x).then(f)`. However, historically that was not always the case, the `when` function provided an important entry point to the library, e.g. in [this version (10/2011)](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/d310253494ed5ba73b2bc6bac8f9b68b7f031fd5/when.js#L303-L321) or the [initial commit (5/2011)](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/9b1eb4e74b52f126362d4a0cf8f86af87d8a8986/when.js#L86-L103).
Interesting is also the [commit *Architectural decision that when() should always return a promise*](https://github.com/cujojs/when/commit/5b41afa79c7bd9807887c55f6a0307ebb89a2503) ([result, 9/2011](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/5b41afa79c7bd9807887c55f6a0307ebb89a2503/when.js#L197-L224)). Groundbreaking work, really :-)

Comment: Ah OK, in that case `when(x,f)` is a piece of unnecessary sugar - a rebel without a cause.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: The cause is mainly historic it seems.

Comment: You know, `git blame` is a really useful tool :-)